# Llamada procedimento desde java

Tags: java

Tengo una base datos creada con el gestor hsqldb.

Dentro de ese esquema tengo un procedimiento que es el siguiente:

```
create procedure insertarUsuario
(nombre varchar(50), apellidos varchar(50), usuariowin varchar(10),xlnet varchar(10), correo varchar(150), planta integer, telefono integer)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO USUARIOS VALUES(nombre, apellidos, usuariowin, xlnet,correo,planta,telefono);
end;
```

Dicho procedimiento lo llamo de la siguiente forma en java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
   ConexionBBDD con = new ConexionBBDD();

    String sql = "{call public.insertarUsuario(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

    CallableStatement cs = con.getConnection().prepareCall(sql);

        cs.setString(1, "esto");
        cs.setString(2, "es");
        cs.setString(3, "una");
        cs.setString(4, "prueba");
        cs.setString(5, "insercion");
        cs.setInt(6, 1);
        cs.setInt(7, 2);

        cs.execute();
        cs.close();

        con.desconexionBBDD();  
}
```

Y esto es lo que java me devuelve:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: INSERTARUSUARIO
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCCallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareCall(Unknown Source)
    at ventanas.pruebaConexion.main(pruebaConexion.java:28)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: INSERTARUSUARIO
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readColumnOrFunctionExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesFactor(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesCommonValueExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadValueExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileCallStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Si hago un `call` en el gestor me lo hace bien, si hago ese mismo `call` a un oracle rula pero aquí me casca.

Answer (score -2):

Solucionado.
La pega estaba en el archivo de conexión que tenia una cosa que no venia a cuento asi que pegaba el casque.

Comment: Hola Bruno. Esta no es una respuesta de calidad. Mira [answer] para mejorarla. Has de explicar qué error habia y como lo solucionaste. Un saludo